# Efficient way to handle webhook by AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, webhooks, serverless

I'm new to AWS. I need to write serverless app that can handle webhook from some website and store data from them

I have defined my own AWS structure like this picture API GATEWAY receives data from Webhook => trigger LAMBDA FUNCTION send data to the client so the client UI will be updated, it's also trigger EVENT BRIDGE rules so RELATED LAMBDA FUNCTION / SERVICE will update data in the database and do some other things.

So do you guys think is there any problem with this structure? Do I need to improve it more?

[image: My app structure]